# Question about factor of a function

Tags: factoring

can you explain this question for me? I don't quite understand it.
Thank you in advance.

> $x^2+1$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Which of the following is TRUE?
>
> $\text{a)}\qquad f(-1)=0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\, \text{d)}\qquad f(x)\text{ has an $x$-intercept of $1$}$
>
> $\text{b)}\qquad f(x)\text{ has a $y$-intercept of $-1$.} \qquad \text{e)}\qquad f(0)=1$
>
> $\text{c)}\qquad f(i)=0\text{ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$}$

Comment: The Question seems to presuppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial, since otherwise "is a factor of" would not have an evident meaning.

Comment: @user115667 can you tell us what attempt you have made to solve this for yourself?

Comment: What exactly don't you get? Everything? in that case, study. otherwise, please be more specific...

Answer (score 2):

We say that $x^2+1$ is a **factor** of the polynomial $P(x)$ is there is a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $(x^2+1)Q(x)=P(x)$.